# Feature Layer Information not showing in SQL table

Tags: arcgis-10.1, sql-server, feature-layer

I have a layer in ArcMap to which data is added via my platform. When the data is added I can see the added feature information by either right clicking on the layer open in arcmap and opening the attributes table to see the feature, or else by going to the SQL database to which the layer is connected and locating the information in the respectively linked table.

Up until end of last week this was working fine, however I ran some tests to check some performance issues by renaming the tables in SQL that were linked and creating new empty table in their place with the old names to preserve the links. When data was added to ArcMap like this all still worked fine as the feature additions were reflected in the new tables.

However I then decided to revert back by deleting the new tables and renaming back the old tables to preserve the links, and this is where the 'issue' occurred. Adding a new feature to the layer will add it on arcmap and will make it visible in the arcmap layer attribute table, however once I go to the SQL table it isn't visible there. I would assume that if there was an issue with storing the new feature it wouldn't be shown in the ArcMap attribute table either. I also restarted both SQL Server as well as ArcGIS Server but the results are still the same.

Is there any reason why data seems to be added but isn't being displayed in the SQL table?

Comment: Well, you've corrupted your geodatabase metadata, so it's difficult to determine how to regain stability. If you really are using the now-Retired 10.1, you don't even have the possibility of asking Tech Support for assistance. Rolling back to a previous backup will be *way* easier than trying to fix a likely half-dozen things without someone on a two-hour trouble-shooting phone call.

Comment: A previous backup of the database? As all that was done was renaming the table and then naming it back to the original, in fact the processes using the mentioned table still worked fine.